# Importing data from JSON link into R

Tags: json, r

```
region_opinion_favor <-
fromJSON("http://ava.publicreligion.org/ajx_map.regionsdata?
category=lgbt_ssm&#038;sc=2&#038;year=2015&#038;topic=lgbt")$regions
```

Here is the error:

```
Error in parse_con(txt, bigint_as_char) : 
 lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                   <!DOCTYPE html>    <!--[if IE 8
                 (right here) ------^`
```

Any advice on how to parse this correctly?

I'm trying to reproduce this visualization:

http://nandeshwar.info/data-visualization/wall-street-journal-data-visualization-r/

Comment: If you go to `http://ava.publicreligion.org/ajx_map.regionsdata?
category=lgbt_ssm&#038;sc=2&#038;year=2015&#038;topic=lgbt` you dont get an JSON file but a web page. You probably need another link

Answer (score 1):

The site has change the URL.
It looks like the query you posted is about the data of who is in favor of same-sex marriage.
If you inspect the HTTP request via for example Chrome Dev tools you find out that the new URL is `http://ava.prri.org/ajx_map.statesdata?category=lgbt_ssm&sc=2&year=2015&topic=lgbt`

so the following code works:

```
> region_opinion_favor <- > fromJSON("http://ava.prri.org/ajx_map.regionsdata?category=lgbt_ssm&sc=2&year=2015&topic=lgbt")$region
sort percent   region
1    0      53 national
2    1      63        1
3    2      54        2
4    3      46        3
5    4      59        4
```

For other datasets, adapt it accordingly.
HTH